# Naming convention for Class with prefix domain name?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have seen lot projects following this kind of coding style

Any significant advantage the following syntax

My project name : King Author(KA)

I  am  going create button components. My class name "KAButton"

Is it right approach and what about namespace?

Also please suggest naming convention for GUI components(Flex/Html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conventional way of naming classes is

com.yourdomain.project.projectompontent.yourclassname.as (or mxml)

Or in your case

com.yourdomain.kingauthor.buttons.RadioButton.as

Advantages:

- There will be no duplicates. You can use this code in combination
  with components from third parties (or they can use yours), without having to be afraid to have a duplicate Class Definition. This is the case because you are using a unique part in your namespace: your domain.
- You can structure your projects easily in subcomponents and third party developers are going to have a faster overview of your project.

Your suggested naming conventions have some disadvantages on top:

- Naming a button KAButton is not self speaking: People have to know that KA stands for King Author and they will have no clue what it is about without looking at the code / documentation.

You can avoid this by using a component based convention and you gain structure for your project.

Comment: Thanks shredding. i really appreciated your respone.

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript already provide a package mechanism, so no need to prefix classes like it's sometime done in C++.

Just put the class in your own package:

```
package com.example {
    class Button {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what shredding said is just right, but some people add such prefixes on their class names so kingauthor.RadioButton doesn't clash with flash.RadioButton in any circumstance. 
for instance, box2dflash uses b2World, b2Body.. and i remember seeing other libs following the same.

i personally would definitely use kingauthor.buttons.kaRadioButton..

Comment: I disagree with using prefixes in all cases except for interfaces (where it's name should be `ISomeInterface`). There's no point adding `ka` to all of your classes as it becomes redundant (you'll see some old school C programmers prefixing all their classes with `C`, which is equally inane). For the Box2D example, I believe it's like that because it's a straight port of the original project

Comment: ultimately it's obviously personal preference in any case. there was a time when naming movieclips with _mc was a standard, but it fell thru these days mainly because people got fed up with that i suppose (or as you point out, was redundant). on another note, i've seen people wondering if there was a way to make FDT use starling framework prior to flash.* packages, just because there are (for instance Sprite) classes in both packages. then again, if it was SSprite or StlSprite, that wouldnt come up. i dont like it, but it is that or name the class something completely different.

Comment: on the plus side, if the implementations are similar you could just do a search and replace on all the imports in your project to get a quick and dirty Starling game :D